# Can I modify a mouse hardware so a single click is always a double click?

Tags: mouse

I am using a KVM switch that can only switch between computers using the mouse wheel double click.  Often my double click does not register because I do it too fast or something, so the clicks end up doing things on the machine I am on.  I would like to modify the hardware of the mouse so that a single mouse click turns into a double mouse click.

This needs to be a physical modification because the KVM needs to register the double click (not the OS, which sits behind the KVM switch).

I have tried to search for a solution, but everything that comes up is unwanted double clicking (please someone, send me your broken mouse with this "enhancement"!).  Any ideas on how to modify a mouse to perform a double click instead of single click?

Comment: Some mice have programmable firmware, which is a much easier option. For example, the Logitech G602 I use should work. You'll need a direct connection to program it, but once that's done it should work without software support. I'll check if it can do middle button double click in firmware mode when I get home.

Comment: There is a program "X-Mouse Button Control" that would act as software for mouses that you dont get a lot of configurable software for, or for obsoleted software. It has vast capability for hotkey and click adjustments  including that. If the OS (it can) or the software does not recognise the clicks (too fast, too slow) sent via the OS and its drivers , it may not be fixable. Luckiliy some of it will support a variable delay, so you could tune to get it to occur more often as desired. . It would be important to Tag your question for the operating system your using.

Comment: @Bob, thanks, just the kind of info I needed.  I just Googled programmable firmware and mouse and came up with a lot of possibilities.  In the end, I went with a Logitech G502 and programmed a macro with a double mouse wheel click.

Comment: @Psycogeek thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately, the KVM switch sits between the mouse and the OS, so the solution has to rely on the mouse only without drivers/software.

Comment: @key2starz Unfortunately, the G602 does not support double-clicks, though it's unclear if that's an actual firmware limitation or if Logitech just [disabled it](http://www.worldcadaccess.com/blog/2014/10/logitech-removed-double-clicking-from-its-mice-how-to-get-it-back.html). Though if the G502 works for you, great! If not - you can look into other programmable mice. You can self-answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying the hardware, instead purchase a mouse that has programmable firmware.

There are several on the market.  I went with the Logitech G502 (figuring out exactly how to program it with the included software was counter-intuitive, but you just have to right-click over the box on the Multikey Macro area that says "Keystrokes" to manually add mouse button functions to the macro).  Some other mice like the Roccat Kone Pure Optical looks like it has even more precise programming options.

These mice are plug-and-play: even though the software is needed in order to modify the macros and store them in the on-board memory, no software/drivers are necessary for the macros stored in the mice to work when the mouse is plugged in to other computers.